# 3D plot of Meshgrid vs. Labeling Matrix

Tags: python, numpy, 3d

Suppose that we want to plot an `n-by-n` meshgrid using `Axes3d`. if we have an `n-by-n` labeling matrix containing `0` and `1`, how can we set the meshgrid pixel colors according to the labeling matrix that we have in a 3D plot?

Comment: For visualization of n*n binary matrix, I'd rather use matplotlib's `pcolormesh` or `imshow` than mplot3d tools... See example here : http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/pcolor_demo.html 

Note that yevgeniy solution can be used for `pcolormesh`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(**Edited**). There is a tutorial on matplotlib: http://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/tutorial.html. Look up `plot_surface` function. All you need to do is to convert your labeling mask to favorite colors. You can either do it via tuple method described in the tutorial, or through pregenerated char matrices as I've done below:

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from matplotlib import cm
from matplotlib.ticker import LinearLocator
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

N=10        # matrix size

c1=np.random.randint(2,size=(N,N))  # your mask of 0 and 1
c2=1-c1                             # inverted mask
char1 = np.chararray((N, N))
char1[:] = 'r'                      # color1
char2=np.chararray((N, N))
char2[:]='b'                        # color2


colors=c1*char1+c2*char2            # color mask for plotting

data=np.random.rand(N,N)*5          # data you are plotting

X=linspace(-3,3,N)
Y=linspace(0,4,N)
X,Y=meshgrid(X,Y)
Z=data

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
surf = ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, rstride=1, cstride=1, facecolors=colors,linewidth=0, antialiased=False)

plt.show()
```